# Bind a widget from inside a class

Tags: python, tkinter

Every example I've seen on this subject has shown a Button being bound to a command, except the Button widget was being made outside of a class:

e.g.:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y 

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100) 
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback) 
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Now that's fine, except I get errors when attempting to do the following:

```
from Tkinter import *
class App():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        o = Button(root, text = 'Open', command = openFile)
        o.pack()
    def openFile(self):
        print 'foo'


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Replacing "command = openFile" with "command = self.openFile()" or "command = openFile()" also does not work.

How do I bind a function to a Button within my class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`command = self.openFile`

If you type `command = self.openFile()` you actually call the method and set the return value as the command. Accessing it without the brackets (like in the non-class version) gets you the actual method object. You need the `self.` in the front, because otherwise Python attempts to look up `openFile` from the global namespace.

The difference between `App.openFile` and `self.openFile` is that the latter is bound to the specific instance, whereas the first needs to be provided with an instance of `App` when later calling it. The [Python Data Model document](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) contains more information about bound and unbound methods.

Answer (score 1):

If event handler declaration is:

```
def handler(self):
```

It should be:

```
def handler(self,event):
```

This is because `tk.bind()` insert the `event` as implicit parameter to the handler. This happens no matters if `event_handler` method is in a class or outside. Inside a class python adds on its own the `self` object.

Sometimes, simplicity tends to obscure reality.